# Micro Frontends, Using angular framework as externals

Tags: angular

We are trying to split the a big front-end application (app.mydomain.com) into 2 smaller applications

1. **Pre-Login application (prelogin.mydomain.com)** - This includes everything before the user logs in
2. **Post-Login application (postlogin.mydomain.com)** - This includes everything after the user logs in

Both of these applications use angular framework which is currently being bundled along with other java-script files. Since angular framework is quite big in size, this increases the bundle size and hence impacts the frontend page loading performance.

Since both of these micro applications are using the angular framework, we don't want to reload angular for second time (when user switches from prelogin to postlogin). Instead, we want to load angular as a external script from third domain (third.mydomain.com) and cache it in browser for future uses. Hence, when user switches from prelogin to postlogin, instead of loading the bundle again, a cached angular bundle from browser will be used.

I could not find anything in Official angular documentation which talks about loading angular in HTML (as a external script). Is this something which angular supports? Does angular provides a UMD module?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be able to use the `System JS` setup to accomplish this: https://jsfiddle.net/angulartypescript/n305zyya/

However, I'm not sure how well that will play with projects already scaffolded with the CLI.

Might it not be easier to bundle these projects together somehow? That way you wouldn't be making any network requests for big packages like the angular core. I have worked on projects where one angular project is bundled like a library and imported into another. Perhaps that would work here?

Comment: I agree that you should try to make it one project... Is there a specific use case you are looking for by splitting it?

Comment: @MyCah - Its a business need. We may need to use same prelogin application for multiple post-login applications. Its same as accounts.google.com which is used for authentication of calendar.google.com and mail.google.com

Comment: @ManavManocha in that case I would just leave Angular in both applications, it's not **that** big and you don't reduce much overhead by having to make a network request for it, even if it's cached. I've made a lot of applications with Angular and none of them have had bad performance simply as a result of the size of Angular.

Comment: @MyCah- I was concerned more about the angular dependencies e.g. RxJS and Zone.js which are quite big in size. What do you think?

Comment: I would think you'd still be fine, especially if you can only import what you need for rxjs your bundle shouldn't end up using the whole library. You could also, if the pre login app is simple enough, just use some smaller framework like Vue and then use angular for the more complex post login.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I agree with @ljolz -- you should be fine. The dependency will have be loaded either way, so there really isn't a way around it.